# Can't get PHP modal contact form to submit email

Tags: php, contact-form

The modal form below gets stuck on submitting....     It also doesn't actually send the message to my email. I am relatively new to PHP, but I assume this problem pertains to my `sendmessage.php` file(below). For whatever reason, the tutorial states to not apply an action. What coud I be doing wrong?

Just FYI, my header contains scripts to `jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6` and `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js`

sendmessage.php file:

```
<?php
$sendto   = "jjaylad@me.com";
$usermail = $_POST['email'];
$content  = nl2br($_POST['msg']);

$subject  = "New Feedback Message";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>New User Feedback</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";


if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

Contact form code:

```
    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
    <label for="email">Your E-mail Address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
    <br>
    <label for="msg">Inquiry:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>

    <button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
</form>
```

Comment: remove Error Control Operator `@` of the mail() function and see what is the error!

Comment: avoid posting your personal details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form `action` should point to `sendmessage.php`

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="sendmessage.php" method="post">
    <label for="email">Your E-mail Address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
    <br>
    <label for="msg">Inquiry:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>
    <button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks tons. A tutorial I used stated this should be filled in, but this was the problem.

Comment: Thanks. You figured it out... this file was still in my fancybox folder, not my site root. I'm terrible at thoroughly troubleshooting on my own! I did notice that others who used the same tutorials(jenniferperrin.com/blog/jquery-tutorial-popup-modal-contact-form/ ) and (http://designwoop.com/2012/07/tutorial-coding-a-jquery-popup-modal-contact-form/) faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing a file.

I get a 404 error when submitting. http://www.jjayladslair.com/sendmessage.php does not exist.

Double check the filenames?

*edit:

Just noticed that you are in fact using $.ajax to process the form. It's most definitely a case of a missing file, or incorrect filename. The 404 error causes a jQuery exception which then stops the execution of the Javascript function.
That's why the form gets stuck on submit.

Comment: The Javascript console is your best friend. I believe most browsers have it built-in nowadays. Very handy for debugging. I have console.log()'s all over the place. Plus jQuery reports all errors there.